# Show console output of a downstream job in upstream job

Tags: logging, jenkins, console

I'm using Jenkins.

Jenkins has a upstream job    : A
Jenkins has a downstream job : B

A's console log output is:

```
1
2
3
```

B's console log output is:

```
A
B
C
```

What I'm trying to get is:

IS there any way, I can get the console output of job B in Job A's console log and THEN, make a decision whether the JOB "A" was successful or not (using log parsing/grep a keyword for failuer/errors etc).

Comment: I have been looking for the same answer and haven't found one.

Comment: I was thinking of using this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin to copy artifact file from downstream to upstream. I don't know if plugin will be able to solve the problem or not.

Comment: The question's title doesn't match its description: _getting the console output from downstream to upstream_ vs. _setting upstream's build result depending on downstream_. If it is the question's title you're interested in see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573477/1744774) to [Output the console text of a Jenkins job that my Job is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521030/output-the-console-text-of-a-jenkins-job-that-my-job-is-running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but it looks rather contrived. See if the following approach fits your needs: start *Job B* from *Job A* via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) as a build step. There is an option for *A* to wait for *B* and then adjust build result for *A* depending on that of *B*.

Comment: If I select that option for A to wait, and if B fails, then do I need to do any log checking to find an error or will it automatically mark the job A failed if B fails (by any means).

Comment: It will automatically mark A as failed if you select the appropriate option.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and easy way is to just use curl

i.e.

```
curl http://myJenkinsServer:9090/job/ProjectNamel/$childJobLastBuildNumber/consoleFull  | sed "s#<span class="timestamp"><b>##g;s#</b> </span># #g"
```

... where $childJobLastBuildNumber is the latest / last build# of the child/downstream job.

Using curl and sed - now I can show the output of child/downstream job in parent job if I run the above *curl | sed ..* command in **Execute Shell**.

Comment: What is the easiest way to assign the correct value to `$childJobLastBuildNUmber`

Comment: Job A --> call Job B. Job B, will create a file (ex: properties.txt) in Job A's workspace (which you can pass to Job B as a parameter) and inserts a key=value pair in it (ex: JOB_B_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER) i.e. now Job A's workspace will have this properties.txt file containing the above variable=value. When Job B completes and control comes back to Job A, you can use $JOB_B_BUILD_NUMBER in place of $childJobLastBuildNumber or set this variable to the value of JOB_B_BUILD_NUMBER and use curl. There are also other easy way like, just `cat path/jobBFullConsoleOutput` in Job A's build section.

Answer (score 0):

**To get the console output of job B.**

I haven't found a better approach than displaying the job log file with `cat`. You'll have to make the "job B trigger" step as a `block`. So that job A won't finish until job B does. Then after the "job B trigger" step, add a step to execute a shell script.

```
cat "$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<PATH_TO_YOUR_JOB>/builds/$TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_<FOLDER_AND_JOB_NAME>/log"
```

Note that `$TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_<FOLDER_AND_JOB_NAME>` is an environment variable injected by Jenkins dynamically.

**To decide whether job A fails or not based on job B.**

You don't have to parse the downstream job's console output. In the upstream job's configuration, when triggering job B, you have the options to choose from. Like:

> - Fail this build step if the triggered build is worse or equal to
> - Mark this build as failure if the triggered build is worse or equal to
> - Mark this build as unstable if the triggered build is worse or equal to