# Output the console text of a Jenkins job that my Job is running

Tags: groovy, jenkins, console, output

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834228/include-downstream-child-jenkins-jobs-console-output-into-triggering-jobs-cons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371383/show-console-output-of-a-downstream-job-in-upstream-job) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572905/how-to-pass-output-from-an-upstream-project-to-downstream-projects-in-jenkins).

I am using the dsl flow. And I would like to be able to see the console log printed out of the job i'm building within the job I'm running. I tried looking around for examples and I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for. I apologize if this question is not using the correct terminology or that it's been asked in different ways. I just want to find the answer of how to do this.

```
A = build("Main Suites", SUITE: "qa_smoketests", OS: "mac")
```

below I tried to do this but it didn't seem to work

```
OUTPUT = A.build.doConsoleText()
out.println(OUTPUT)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried the 2nd method to update it on the fly and I keep getting an issue with the url? strangely if I click the url link in the error it takes me to the appropriate page. I did have to modify things b/c the Job name has spaces in it. I also edited my error log for this post to say **MYHOSTURL** instead of my actual Jenkins host url.

```
ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://MYHOSTURL/job/Main%20Suites/159/consoleText
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at java_util_concurrent_Future$get$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate$_parallel_closure6.doCall(FlowDSL.groovy:440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1351)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$170.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.parallel(FlowDSL.groovy:438)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10240.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:723)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.invokeMethod(FlowDSL.groovy)
    at hudson.util.spring.ClosureScript.invokeMethod(ClosureScript.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:12)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDSL.executeFlowScript(FlowDSL.groovy:84)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowRun$FlyweightTaskRunnerImpl.run(FlowRun.java:219)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowRun.run(FlowRun.java:155)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
    at hudson.model.OneOffExecutor.run(OneOffExecutor.java:43)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://MYHOSTURL/job/Main%20Suites/159/consoleText
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://MYHOSTURL/job/Main%20Suites/159/consoleText
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$getInputStream.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at Script1.responseFrom(Script1.groovy:82)
    at Script1$responseFrom.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at Script1.printConsoleOutputTextChunksFrom(Script1.groovy:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at Script1$_run_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at Script1$_run_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate$_parallel_closure5_closure7.doCall(FlowDSL.groovy:427)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8673.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate$_parallel_closure5_closure7.doCall(FlowDSL.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8672.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    ... 9 more
}
Finished: FAILURE
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So I was able to get the first method working by modifying the responseFrom function to handle a page that needs authentication.

```
InputStream responseFrom(String url)
  {
  // See Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests 
  //     https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1744774
  URL myURL = new URL(url);
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
  String userCredentials = "username:password";
  String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes());
  String basicAuth = "Basic " + encoding;
  connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
  return connection.getInputStream();  
  }
```

However I'm still having issues getting the 2nd method to work. I guess it's with the function that is being used to get the build number from the downstream job.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
>   java.lang.Integer.parseUnsignedInt() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [164]

Comment: Re _"No signature of method: static java.lang.Integer.parseUnsignedInt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)"._ [Integer.parseUnsignedInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-) states _"Since: 1.8"._ Try [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) if you're using a version prior to 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
        myjob=build job: 'job path', parameters: [
             ...
           ], propagate: true, wait: true  
        
         echo "${myjob.getResult()}"
         println myjob.getRawBuild().getLog()
```

getResult is just 'SUCCESS/FAILURE' but
getRaWBuild().getLog() has the output of the called job.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. I can't comprehend the downvote.

- The first of your links describes how you should be able to do it: via *"repeated GET requests"*.
- The second is about setting the result of an upstream job according to the content of a downstream job's console output. This can be achieved easier by something else but parsing the console output.
- The third is about the opposite direction: passing output from an upstream job to a downstream job.

I'm going to try the first and will update this answer accordingly then.

#### UPDATE 1

The following updates the upstream's log once the downstream build has finished.

```
// From: Output the console text of a Jenkins job that my Job is running
//       http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573477/1744774
final String JENKINS_HOST = 'http://<your Jenkins host>'
final String DOWNSTREAM_NAME = '<your downstream job's name>'

final String SEPARATOR = new String(new char[8]).replace('\0', '-')
final int DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO = build(DOWNSTREAM_NAME).getBuild().getNumber()

println("${SEPARATOR} Begin console HTML output of ${DOWNSTREAM_NAME} #${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO} ${SEPARATOR}")
printConsoleOutputHtmlFrom(
    "${JENKINS_HOST}/job/${DOWNSTREAM_NAME}/${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO}/console")

println("${SEPARATOR} Begin console text output of ${DOWNSTREAM_NAME} #${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO} ${SEPARATOR}")
printConsoleOutputTextFrom(
    "${JENKINS_HOST}/job/${DOWNSTREAM_NAME}/${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO}/consoleText")

println("${SEPARATOR} End console output of ${DOWNSTREAM_NAME} ${SEPARATOR}")

import org.xml.sax.InputSource

void printConsoleOutputHtmlFrom(String consoleUrl)
  {
  println(xPathExpression('//pre[contains(@class, "console-output")]')
              .evaluate(new InputSource(responseFrom(consoleUrl))))
  }

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

void printConsoleOutputTextFrom(String consoleTextUrl)
  {
  BufferedReader log = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(responseFrom(consoleTextUrl), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
  while ((line = log.readLine()) != null)
    {
    println(line)
    }
  }

InputStream responseFrom(String url)
  {
  // See Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests 
  //     http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1744774
  URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
  return connection.getInputStream();  
  }

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

XPathExpression xPathExpression(String expression)
  {
  // See How to read XML using XPath in Java
  //     http://stackoverflow.com/a/2811101/1744774
  XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
  return xPath.compile(expression);
  }
```

References:

- [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)
- [com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.JobInvocation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-flow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/cloudbees/plugins/flow/JobInvocation.groovy) (returned by `build()`)
- [hudson.model.Run](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html) (returned by `JobInvocation.getBuild()`)

#### UPDATE 2

The following updates the upstream's log on the fly.

```
// From: Output the console text of a Jenkins job that my Job is running
//       http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573477/1744774
final String JENKINS_HOST = 'http://<your Jenkins host>'
final String DOWNSTREAM_NAME = '<your downstream job's name>'

final String SEPARATOR = new String(new char[8]).replace('\0', '-')

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

parallel(
  { build(DOWNSTREAM_NAME) },
  {
  final String THIS_BUILD_NAME = build.getProject().getName()
  final int THIS_BUILD_NO = build.getNumber()
  final int DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO = downstreamBuildNoFrom(
      "${JENKINS_HOST}/job/${THIS_BUILD_NAME}/${THIS_BUILD_NO}/consoleText") 
    
  println("${SEPARATOR} Begin console output of ${DOWNSTREAM_NAME} #${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO} ${SEPARATOR}")
  
  printConsoleOutputTextChunksFrom(
      "${JENKINS_HOST}/job/${DOWNSTREAM_NAME}/${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO}/consoleText", 3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  
  println("${SEPARATOR} End console output of ${DOWNSTREAM_NAME} #${DOWNSTREAM_BUILD_NO} ${SEPARATOR}")
  })

int downstreamBuildNoFrom(String thisBuildConsoleTextUrl)
  {
  int downstreamBuildNo = -1
  while (downstreamBuildNo <= 0)
    {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L)
    BufferedReader log = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(responseFrom(thisBuildConsoleTextUrl), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    while ((line = log.readLine()) != null)
      {
      if (line.matches('.* Build .* started'))
        {
        final int buildNoIdx = line.indexOf('#') + 1
        downstreamBuildNo = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(
            line.substring(buildNoIdx, line.indexOf(' ', buildNoIdx)))
        break
        }
      /*if (log.lines().anyMatch(t -> t.matches(".* Build .* started")))
        {
        // in case of Java >=8
        }*/
      }
    }
  return downstreamBuildNo
  } // downstreamBuildNoFrom()

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

void printConsoleOutputTextChunksFrom(String consoleTextUrl, long updateInterval, TimeUnit updateIntervalUnit)
  {
  final int LINE_BREAK_LENGTH = System.getProperty("line.separator").length()
  int charsPrintedSoFar = 0
  while (true) // effectively a do { ... }
    {
    int charsPrintedThisTime = 0
    BufferedReader chunk = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(responseFrom(consoleTextUrl), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))
    chunk.skip(charsPrintedSoFar)
    while ((line = chunk.readLine()) != null)
      {
      println(line)
      charsPrintedThisTime = line.length() + LINE_BREAK_LENGTH
      charsPrintedSoFar += charsPrintedThisTime
      }
    updateIntervalUnit.sleep(updateInterval)
    if (charsPrintedThisTime == 0)
      break
    } 
  } // printConsoleOutputTextChunksFrom()

InputStream responseFrom(String url)
  {
  // See Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests 
  //     http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1744774
  URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
  return connection.getInputStream();  
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your kindness and efforts. I think I might of been       downvoted because originally I just said I looked at examples but I didn't link them.    
I'm still pretty new to Jenkins. I thought maybe I could use the below method to print out the contents of the link.    

    `buildnumber = A.build.number`    

    `OUTPUT = "myurl" + buildnumber + "/logText/progressiveHtml"`     

I don't know how to display the contents of that link? It would be ideal to simulate exactly how the console output looks on the downstream job. Where it updates in realtime.

Comment: @BarretV Do the implementations in the updates to my answer suit your needs?

Comment: well I'm not sure if it's my console output that is causing the problem. I'm outputting the results of a suite of protractor tests and a few times it would output the results and other times it ran into error with the xml parsing. I'm guessing some of the characters aren't allowed.

Comment: @BarretV Does it always happen at the same job(s) or at random jobs? On which line does the error occur and which is it in detail? Can you supply the log of a job that failed? Do you mean Protractor, or something else, doesn't write character references for [predefined entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) but the character itself?

Comment: yes i'm using protractor. unfortunately we only keep the last 20 runs of our tests so the errors I was getting aren't appearing anymore.  I am also using jasmine-spec-reporter for the console output . Here is an example of the output that you might see https://gist.github.com/bvasilchik/38ff064f89df307534a8

Comment: @BarretV Did you use the code of **UPDATE 1**? The code under **UPDATE 2** doesn't use `xpathExpression.`