# Get live logs of a triggered jenkins pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am triggering pipeline2 from pipeline1.
Inside jenkinsfile of pipeline1 I have something like the following

```
build job: 'pipeline2'
```

But this doesn't post the live logs of pipeline2 in pipeline1. Is there a way to post the live logs of the downstream job in upstream job console?

Answer (score 1):

This can partially be achieved by returning a build object,

```
buildobj = build job: 'pipeline2'
echo buildobj.rawBuild.log
```

But this doesn't echo live logs rather prints everything at once after build is executed.

Comment: We also have an upstream job only printed rawbuild of the downstream job in case of a failure (after the job has run). But, we did not look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573477/8195106. Have you tried that?